# Add FAQ structured data snippets to Nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, next.js13

I'm working on a blog using NextJs13 and Strapi and in some pages/posts, I have a FAQ section.

I'm rendering my page **SERVER SIDE**

I used this solution on my `[slug]/page.tsx`:

```js
const Place = async ({
  params,
}: {
  params: { slug: string; city: string; lang: string };
}) => {
  const id = params.slug.split('-').slice(-1)[0];
  if (!Number.isFinite(parseInt(id))) {
    notFound();
  }
  const place = await fetchPlace(id);
  const morePlaces = await fetchMorePlaces();

  if (
    params.slug != `${slugify(place.name)}-${place.id}` ||
    params.city != place.city
  ) {
    redirect(
      `/${place.city}/${params.lang}/places/${slugify(place.name)}-${place.id}`
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Script id="faq-schema" strategy="afterInteractive">
        {JSON.stringify({
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "FAQPage",
          "mainEntity": place.faq && place.faq.length > 0 && place.faq.map((item) => ({
            "@type": "Question",
            "name": item.title,
            "acceptedAnswer": {
              "@type": "Answer",
              "text": item.content,
            },
          }))
        })}
      </Script>

      <Carousel place={place} />
      <Layout>
        <div className="lg:pt-40 lg:pb-24 md:py-32 sm:py-24 py-8 lg:px-28 md:px-20">
          <Header place={place} />
          <Content place={place} />
          {place.faq && place.faq.length > 0 && <FAQSection faq={place.faq} />}
        </div>
        <CardsSection places={morePlaces} params={params} />
      </Layout>
      <StickyDiv />
    </>
  );
};
```

But it seems that this solution is not working and doesn't get detected by google, and it somehow triggers an error on the development server saying : `Unhandled Runtime Error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`

How can I add the FAQ structured data snippets to my code and make it work correctly and detected by google. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the structured data for your script tag as children render them directly as raw markup as seen below. Furthermore, there is no need to use the `next/script` component for this purpose. A normal script tag will suffice.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const schema = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "FAQPage",
    mainEntity:
      place.faq &&
      place.faq.length > 0 &&
      place.faq.map((item) => ({
        "@type": "Question",
        name: item.title,
        acceptedAnswer: {
          "@type": "Answer",
          text: item.content,
        },
      })),
  };

  return (
    <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: JSON.stringify(schema),
      }}
    />
  );
};
```